# Getting Compiling Error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is the task I was given:

Write a function `fact_calc` that takes a string output argument and an integer input argument `n` and returns a string showing the calculation of `n!`. For example, if the value supplied for `n` were 6, the string returned would be
`“6! x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 x = 720”`. Write a program that repeatedly prompts the user for an integer between 0 and 9, calls `fact_calc` and outputs the resulting string in a box of asterisks of the right size to surround the result. If the user inputs an invalid value, the program should display an error message and reprompt for valid input. Input of the sentinel -1 should cause the input loop to exit.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*Prototypes*/
void fact_calc(char [], int);

int main(void)
{
   char calc[99];
   int num1;

   do{

      printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 9 or -1 to quit: ");
      scanf("%d", &num1);

      fact_calc(calc, num1);

   }while( num1 != -1 );


   return (0);
 } //end main

 /*Place function definitions below*/
 void fact_calc(char calc[], int num1)
 {
   if(num1 == 0)
       char calc[] = "0! = 0 = 0";

   else if(num1 == 1)
      char calc[] = "1! = 1 = 0"

   else if(num1 == 2)
      char calc[99] = "2! = 2 x 1 = 2"

   else if(num1 == 3)
       char calc[99] = "3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6"

   else if(num1 == 4)
      char calc[99] = "4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24"

   else if(num1 == 5)
      char calc[99] = "5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120"

   else if(num1 == 6)
      char calc[99] = "6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720"

   else if(num1 == 7)
      char calc[99] = "7! = 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 5040"

   else if(num1 == 8)
      char calc[99] = "8! = 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 40320"

   else if(num1 == 9)
      char calc[99] = "9! = 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 362880"

   else
      printf("Invalid Entry");   

}
```

I am getting the error:

```
  expected
  expression
  ch...
  ^
```

I still have to print out the string but I can't figure out what the error means or what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
char calc[] = "1! = 1 = 0"
```

Don't you think you should be ending this line with a `;`

```
char calc[] = "1! = 1 = 0";
```

Similar fix needs to be done for the rest of the lines

Comment: The problem is it doesn't make any sense to even have `char calc[] = "1! = 1 = 0";` in his program.

Comment: @ouah Sir, Really I didn't look into what he was trying to do. Just saw that error was because of this. Yes I see your point but it is upto OP what he wants to do

Comment: It should be noted that adding the semicolons does NOT fix the code. Try compiling it with the semicolons added if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign strings (char arrays) in C. You should use `strcpy()` instead.

E.g.

```
strcpy(calc, "2! = 2 x 1 = 2");
```

Note that you should use `strcpy()` only if you are 100% certain `calc` is large enough to store the entire string. If not, use `strncpy()` instead. Example:

```
strncpy(calc, "2! = 2 x 1 = 2", 99);
calc[98] = '\0';
// a better way would be to pass 99 to your function, or to declare a macro
```

Finally, note that both 0! and 1! should be 1, not 0.

Comment: Do you think assigning strings during initialization is also wrong? The point is the OP's code doesn't make sense

Comment: @Gopi I said "you cannot assign strings", not "you cannot initialise strings". I am pointing out to the OP how to fix his code.

Comment: @ace first `sizeof calc` with `calc` the parameter of the function will yield the size of a pointer not of an array, second `strncpy` does not always null terminate its destination buffer so you have to do it manually.

Comment: @ouah sorry for forgetting that; fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your program is doing something strange.  I doubt it does what you expect.

You are declaring variables inside the body of `if` statements.  These variables will only be in scope for the body, and you don't do anything with them.

Your program can be made to work.  I suggest simply making `fact_calc()` return literal strings rather than try to assign to variables.

```
/*Place function definitions below*/
 char const *fact_calc(char calc[], int num1)
 {
   if(num1 == 0)
       return "0! = 0 = 0";

   else if(num1 == 1)
      return "1! = 1 = 0";

   else if(num1 == 2)
      return "2! = 2 x 1 = 2";

   else if(num1 == 3)
       return "3! = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6";

   else if(num1 == 4)
      return "4! = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24";

   else if(num1 == 5)
      return "5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120";

   else if(num1 == 6)
      return "6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720";

   else if(num1 == 7)
      return "7! = 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 5040";

   else if(num1 == 8)
      return "8! = 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 40320";

   else if(num1 == 9)
      return "9! = 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 362880";

  /* Invalid Entry */
  return NULL;
}
```

Then your main function should declare a variable of type `char const *` to store the pointer returned by this function, and should check that the pointer is not set to `NULL` (and print `"Invalid Entry"` if the pointer was set to `NULL`).